# iPhone parse <br /> with Hpple

Tags: iphone

I'm using hpple to parse html: 
Only one question is:

```
<div class="Fiche">
  <p>Every Sunday, our Chef proposes a buffet high in color.
  <br />
  <br />
  A brunch either classic or on a theme for special events (Hallowe&rsquo;en, autumn...). Each time, you will be surprised by new culinary suggestions. Unlimited champagne.<br />
  <br />
  Every Sunday at the restaurant <a target="_blank" href="http://www.montecarlobay.com/THE-BLUE-BAY.html">Le Blue Bay</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  Information/ reservations : (377) 98 06 03 60
 </p>
```

My code is:

```
NSArray *array4Soustitre = [xpathParser search:@"//div [@class='Fiche']/p"];
TFHppleElement *ele= [array4Soustitre objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog(@"content is %@ ",[ele content]);
```

And what i get is only: `Information/ reservations : (377) 98 06 03 60`
I want to get all text between `<p>` and `</p>`, except `<br />`
Any help, great thanks!

Comment: I am having the same problem.
Has anyone found a way to get libXml2 (what Hpple is based on) to allow for <BR /> line brakes?

Comment: try using http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Internet-Utilities/XPath-Helper.shtml this BTW does your application.... freezes when gettin

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
NSArray *array4Soustitre = [xpathParser search:@"//div [@class='Fiche']/p/text()"];
```